# Eclipse tool tip/method info

Tags: java, eclipse

I've been looking around the forum for ways to solve this, but nothing seems to do it.

I want eclipse to show the information of the methods, but it doesn't. It should appear to the right side of this box:

[image: Eclipse screenshot of problem]

I've tried downloading Java SE 8 API documentation and adding it to the installed JRE Javadoc location, but it still doesn't work.

Anyone else who's had this problem and managed to solve it?

Thanks

Comment: canaisAM is an ArrayList, so it should show the info about the remove() methods from ArrayList class. And canaisAM refers to a class Canal which I already commented

Comment: Best is to download the JDK. IDE's tend to hook up to its source automatically once you define it as the default library.

Comment: That actually worked! Thanks @user1803551